# Only keep columns in a dataframe that include a certain string in one of the rows

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, filter

I have about 50 columns and only want to keep columns in a dataframe that include a colon (:) in one of the rows.

Example data:

```
         DATE     CALL_ID   TALK_TIME   SPEED_OF_ANSWER  CONSULT_TIME
0     2023-11-21  29933702       NaN             NaN          NaN
1     2023-11-21  29933703  00:04:16    00:00:01.373          NaN
2     2023-11-21  29933703       NaN             NaN     00:14:10
3     2023-11-21  29933704  00:24:30    00:00:01.391          NaN
4     2023-11-21  29933705  00:04:08    00:00:34.360          NaN
```

Output I want:

```
        TALK_TIME   SPEED_OF_ANSWER  CONSULT_TIME
0            NaN             NaN          NaN
1       00:04:16    00:00:01.373          NaN
2            NaN             NaN     00:14:10
3       00:24:30    00:00:01.391          NaN
4       00:04:08    00:00:34.360          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Craft a boolean mask using [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(':')).any(axis=0)
out = df.loc[:, m]
```

Or, pre-filtering on object columns:

```
m = (df.select_dtypes('object')
       .apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(':'))
       .any(axis=0)
       .reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)
     )
out = df.loc[:, m]
```

Output:

```
  TALK_TIME SPEED_OF_ANSWER CONSULT_TIME
0       NaN             NaN          NaN
1  00:04:16    00:00:01.373          NaN
2       NaN             NaN     00:14:10
3  00:24:30    00:00:01.391          NaN
4  00:04:08    00:00:34.360          NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```py
>>> df.loc[:, df.applymap(lambda s: ':' in str(s)).any(axis=0)]
  TALK_TIME SPEED_OF_ANSWER CONSULT_TIME
0       NaN             NaN          NaN
1  00:04:16    00:00:01.373          NaN
2       NaN             NaN     00:14:10
3  00:24:30    00:00:01.391          NaN
4  00:04:08    00:00:34.360          NaN
```

This is ever so slightly faster (733 µs ± 2.99 µs) than:

```py
df.loc[:, df.astype(str).applymap(lambda s: ':' in s).any(axis=0)]
# 776 µs ± 8.95 µs
```

or

```py
df.loc[:, df.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(':')).any(axis=0)]
# 1.14 ms ± 12 µs
```